# Why can't I see my texture in prevew and render view?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have painted in substance painter and imported the texture. I can see the texture in texture mode. When I render or preview render it  the bottom mesh (body skin) is showing just a basic color. The other mesh (antenna) is showing in both texture mode and in render. I have assigned the texture and uv map also. Any suggestion or help why I can't see it?

### Texture Mode

[image]

### Preview Render

[image]

**Nodes**

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a bit more, like your whole node setup and the active texture in the UV-Editor? Best would be a part of the blend-file.

Comment: @quiliup i have edited uploaded the nodes. It with the node wrangler addon set

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have Subsurface scattering set to 1.00 This is a lot, the green color will overwrite the texture. Try a lower value of Subsurface (0.2 or 0.3 would be my guess)